# Combining update query from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to combine these 2 update query's in 1
And does doing this has any preformance advantage?

```
update AREA
set ID_MasterArea =AREACITY.ID_Area
from  dbo.Area AREA 
JOIN dbo.Address A on AREA.ID_Address = A.ID_Address
JOIN dbo.Area AREACITY on A.ID_City = AREACITY.ID_City
where AREA.ID_MasterArea IS NULL
and  AREA.ID_Address IS NOT NULL

 update AREA
set ID_MasterArea =AREACOUNTRY.ID_Area
from  dbo.Area AREA 
JOIN dbo.City C on AREA.ID_City = c.ID_City
JOIN dbo.Area AREACOUNTRY on C.ID_Country = AREACOUNTRY.ID_Country
where AREA.ID_MasterArea IS NULL
and  AREA.ID_City IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: both queries are different,so combining update wont be correct

Comment: Why are you asking? The two queries use different tables, different conditions and different values. If you want to improve performance, make sure the tables are indexed. The join columns at least should be covered by indexes

Comment: It looks very repetitve for me because I also have to do this for province, city, country,....

Comment: Why do you ask if it's possible?   Did you try something that didn't work?   What was it?

Comment: I want to reduce my code. and make it more easy to adjust, If I can combine these updates in 1 query, I am more satisfied :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Not necessarily improve in performance. It might be more complex to maintain if you merge them with outer joins and conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like this?

```
update AREA
set ID_MasterArea = case when Area.ID_Address is not null then AREACOUNTRY.ID_Area
                    when Area.ID_City is not null then AreaCountry.Id_Area
                    end 
from  dbo.Area AREA 
JOIN dbo.City C on AREA.ID_City = c.ID_City
LEFT JOIN dbo.Area AREACOUNTRY on C.ID_Country = AREACOUNTRY.ID_Country
LEFT JOIN dbo.Address A On Area.ID_Address = A.ID_Address
LEFT JOIN dbo.AREA AREACITY on A.ID_City = AREACITY.ID_City
where AREA.ID_MasterArea IS NULL
```

Check the joins before updating by doing select on what records you are going to update and do the update accordingly if it good